# How can i get the current month of a record from a loop in my blade

Tags: laravel

I am trying to get records from two tables USER & SALES table...but i need only the sales done for the current month for each user.

i am using this function to get all records from the two tables

```
$everyone = User::with('sales')->get();
```

Then in my view i am doing this

```
@foreach($everyone as $item)

$item->sales->sum('sales')

@endforeach
```

but i want to get the sales only for the current month in the view..how can i add where month in the view

I have tried

```
$item->sales->whereMonth('created_at', Carbon::now()->month)->sum('sales')
```

but not working

Comment: use `$item->sales()->whereMonth('created_at', Carbon::now()->format('M'))->sum('sales')` and check what you get.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `whereHas()` method, `whereHas()` works basically the same as `has()` but allows you to specify additional filters for the related **model** to check :

```
$everyone = User::whereHas('sales', function ($query) {
        $query->whereMonth('created_at', Carbon::now()->format('M'));
})->get();
```

> This method doesn't support **Laravel 5.4** anymore. This method is for Laravel 5.5 and higher

The below code has not tested by me. Hope this works :

```
$everyone = User::with(['sales' => function ($query) { 
                   $query->whereMonth('created_at', Carbon::now()->format('M'));
            }])
           ->get();
```

Comment: compact(): Undefined variable: operator

Comment: would you give me the output of `dd($everyone)` ?

Comment: Same thing when i do dd($everyone) i get compact(): Undefined variable: operator

Comment: I make some changed, would you try again? must use `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;` on the top

Comment: Which laravel version you are using?

Comment: i am using 5.4 version

Comment: This method doesn't support 5.4 anymore. This method is for Laravel 5.5 and higher

Comment: how can i do this on 5.4 pls